# What is the maximum number of accusatives you can have in an English sentence?

Tags: english, grammar, valency

I know things like the double-accusative exist in English, like "I call sodas cokes." Then things can get more complex with words like "bet," where you can have "I bet you 5 dollars the coin is heads."

Are there any English verbs that have more direct objects than "bet"? If there's some nuance I'm missing with my question, please let me know.

Comment: “Accusative” is a case name, but English has no cases whatsoever, so “accusatives” is a wrong term. Those things are objects, just as you have it in the question body, but “direct” is also dubious. What's true is that in your examples they're not governed by prepositions. The thing you're to specify is the presence/absence of a preposition before the objects you'd like to focus on, but _not_ their “case” (non-existent in English), _not_ how much direct / indirect the objects are (category irrelevant in English).

Comment: I mean, by the form of an English noun you cannot tell if it's a direct or an indirect object, that distinction is purely logical, so if the name of the addressee is considered the indirect object, then in "I bet you 5 dollars the coin is heads" _you_ is an indirect object, not a direct one. There seems to be no verbs that allow more than 3 prepositionless objects, the ones that allow 3 are _tritransitive_: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valency_(linguistics)
Your question is very English-specific, it's best to ask it at the [English language & Usage SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is "I told him to ask her to pay them" one sentence? Which question are you asking? How about conjunctions ("you and me", "Sue and him"): do you want to include them or exclude them?

Comment: @YellowSky You say that English has no cases whatsoever. But there is a distinction between genitive and plain case, e.g. _Kim's_ vs _Kim_, and a few pronouns have distinct nominative and accusative cases, e.g. _I_ vs _me_ instead of a plain case.

Comment: @BillJ - The category of case is not needed to explain it all, it's superfluous. Occam's razor, you know. The pronoun _I_ belongs to the subjective personal pronouns, together with _he, we,_ and _me_ belongs to the objective personal pronouns together with _him, us_. There are other kinds of personal pronouns: possessive (my, his, our), reflexive (myself, himself). Maybe _my_ is also a case form of _I_? The genitive case of _I_? That _Kim's_ is a possessive form of the noun, other languages have such a form, too. Mostly animate nouns and units of measurement have this form, too few for a case.

Comment: The point is that it is incorrect (or at least misleading) to say that English has no cases whatsoever, when it clearly does, albeit limited to genitive vs plain case nouns, and a few pronouns that have distinct nominative vs accusative cases. _I_ is nominative case, while _me_ is accusative case. _My_, _his_, _our_,  etc. are genitive case pronouns, and the reflexive pronouns can be said to have plain case.

Comment: @BillJ - It is misleading to apply grammar categories of one language to analyze another language. You _cannot prove_ English has a case system. There are some remnants of the old case system in English, but now those forms don't represent cases anymore, they are out of case system. You cannot postulate that only 8 words in a language have nominative - objective case distinction, and the rest tens of thousands of nouns don't have it, and at the same time this language _does have_ cases — the case system doesn't work that way. There's no such thing as “plain case”.

Comment: I disagree. The OP is asking solely about English, so your reference to other languages is irrelevant. The proof is in the form: _I_ _me_ and _my_ are clearly distinct case-forms of the same pronoun and as such can hardly be said to be 'out of the case system. A great many nouns can be inflected for genitive case, and most of the personal pronouns have up to four different case-forms.

Comment: Plain case is defined as a non-genitive case that is neither accusative or nominative: _you_, _cat_, _cats_ etc. See p107 here: [link](https://hostnezt.com/cssfiles/english/A%20Student's%20Introduction%20To%20English%20Grammar%20by%20Huddleston%20Rodney%20&%20Pullum%20Geoffrey%20(CAMBRIDGE)%20x2.pdf)

Comment: @BillJ - How can my be the genitive case form of _I_ if it comes from the Old English _mīn_ which was itself declinable in all the Old English cases, genders and numbers? Just like the Modern German _mein_ (m.): G. _meines_, D. _meinem_, Acc. _meinen_. Not groundless assumptions, but _proofs_ is what is needed. And what is written in a school textbook is just a practical pedagogical guideline having nothing to do with linguistics.

Comment: In Present-day English _my_ is an inflected form, a genitive form, just as _your_, _our_ etc. are. What else could they be? The textbook I linked to is not one intended for schoolchildren, but is written primarily for undergraduates, and is based on the authors' larger work, CGEL. Its primary author, Rodney Huddleston, is recognised as the world’s greatest expert on the grammar of English language so his works are pretty authoritive!

Comment: @BillJ - Your next mission is to find a _proof_ that _my_ is the genitive case form of _I_. Any grammar or dictionary saying that will do. ;)

Comment: See p105 #8.3 of the link I sent you. I'm surprised you haven't already done that.

Comment: So pers. pronouns have Nom., Acc., and Gen. cases, and nouns have Plain and Gen. cases, which means: the only 8 words that have Nom. vs. Acc. distinction are peripheral, 8 words is not enough to state that all the nouns that can have Gen. have their Nom. = Acc., you can't judge about the majority by negligible minority. Thus it comes out English has 2 case systems: one for those 8, the other for the nouns, which is absolutely outstanding since no other Language I know of has 2 case systems. Here Occam's Razor cuts off that weird stuff leaving us with the simplest answer: no case in English.

Comment: I'll tell you more: the function of the case is to show the syntactic function of a nominal respective to the verb: if the nominal is the subject or the object (alternatively the agens or the patiens). Languages that have cases with this function can have other cases, too, like Gen., or local cases, but there can't be a language that has only non-Gen. vs. Gen. cases, without subj. and obj. cases.

Comment: Chinese has the particle 的 _de_ with the same function as the English _’s_, so does Chinese have 2 cases, too? Surely no since it has no Subj. and Obj. markers. English nouns have no Subj. vs Obj. distinction, so English has no case in its universal understanding. Mere 8 words can't account for the existence of the category which encompasses tens of thousands of other words in which the distinction of that category is absent, that's against the rules of common sense. If I have a red ball and my brother has a blue one, I can't assume _all the other_ people have either a red or a blue ball each.

Comment: @YellowSky but just because you are the only one with a red ball doesn't mean that yours is not a ball It doesn't matter whether it exists elsewhere, if it fits the definition of a ball (or a case system) it is considered such. Occam's razor does not apply here. so what if only pronouns have a case system or the case system only has two cases, it is still a case system (albeït a very simplified one) as it tells the function of a word by cahnging its form. A subject object distinction is not necessary.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM - Being able to say ‘you're wrong’ is just what it is, but definitely not a proof I'm wrong. My arguments are above, what are yours, besides ’I disagree’?

Comment: @YellowSky so, instead of saying I am solidly right (which I am not, and do not think myself to be, as this is a matter of opinion) I am goïng to counter your arguments:
1. Saying that *I* and *me* are in completely different categories of pronouns means you could technically argue that *him* is just the third person singular masculine form of *me*, is that correct?
2. For your "too few for a case" statement, I would like evidence, who governs how many inflected words need to be in a language for it to count as an inflected language?  I nay be wrong, but if so, I'd like to know it for sure.

Comment: @YellowSky
3. Who says pronouns and nouns cannot have separate inflectional systems in a language? It makes sense that they might to me, and I really don't see anything wrong with it. 
4. "there can't be a language that has only non-Gen. vs. Gen. cases, without subj. and obj. cases",  why not? A language can have whatever cases evolution chooses, there aren't any certain combinations that just don't count as far as I am aware.
5. "Chinese has the particle 的 de with the same function as the English ’s" I personally would consider it more like "of" than " 's ", so that doesn't really work.

Comment: @YellowSky and finally, 6. If " 's " isn't an inflectional suffix by your understanding, what do you consider it to be? That has me very curiöus. Also as a side note, as I have mentioned before, this is a matter of opinion, what you decide to call whatever English is doïng. Neither sides of this debate can truly be right or wrong. I could argue that bagels are just savoury doughnuts, and still have a (somewhat) valid argument. It all depends on how broadly (or narrowly) you choose to define things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129841/discussion-between-quintus-caesius-rm-and-yellow-sky).

Comment: The fact that Present-day English doesn't have the rich case system that some other languages have doesn't mean that it has no case whatsoever. If you read the link I gave you, you'll have seen that the personal pronouns are inflected for case. Nominative, accusative and genitive are indisputedly cases -- what else could they be? Nouns too have two cases: nominative and plain, and can be inflected for genitive case.

Comment: We might also add that relative and interrogative "who" has case, i.e. nominative _those who we consulted_ vs accusative _those whom we consulted_  /  nominative _Who did you meet?_ vs accusative  _Whom did you meet?_ Thus, there's no reason to say that Present-day English doesn't have case, albeit a remnant of an earlier system.

Comment: Please use Quintus Caesius' chat to continue this discussion, thank you.